# how to show JS alert on open of each tab of the slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the [liquidslider](http://liquidslider.com/documentation/) script on my webpage and I created the slider on my page, the html code looks like this:

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-id">
     <div>
          <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2>
          // Content goes here
     </div>
     <div>
          <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2>
          // Content goes here
     </div>
     <div>
          <h2 class="title">Slide 3</h2>
          // Content goes here
     </div>
</div>
```

There's also my current javascript:

```
$('#slider-1').liquidSlider({
    autoHeight:false,
    slideEaseFunction:'animate.css',
    slideEaseDuration:1000,
    heightEaseDuration:1000,
    animateIn:"fadeIn",
    animateOut:"fadeOut",
    callback: function() {
       var self = this;
       $('.slider-1-panel').each(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('animated ' + self.options.animateIn);
       });
       $('.slider-1-panel').each(function() {
           alert("you opened panel");
       });
     }   
});
```

and currently the message "you opened panel" is shown 4 times each time the user clicks the panel tab, that's because of those lines:

```
$('.slider-1-panel').each(function() {
    alert("you opened panel");
});
```

How can I change it so that the message is displayed only once for each panel? Later on I want to add animations in css to each panel so that they're invoked when the user selects the panel and I thought the good start would be to know when the user selects any panel.

as you suggested, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/), I added resources, but I can't make it up and running properly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong there.. But the css code is visible there, hopefuly that's helpful enough

EDIT:
I've decided to add a little bit more details. I managed to create an option that changes all the tabs while the user clicks any tab:

```
$('#slider-1').liquidSlider({
     autoHeight:false,
  slideEaseFunction:'animate.css',
  slideEaseDuration:1000,
  heightEaseDuration:1000,
  animateIn:"fadeIn",
  animateOut:"fadeOut",
  callback: function() {
    var self = this;
    $('.slider-1-panel').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('animated ' + self.options.animateIn);
    });

    $('#slider-1-nav-ul a').each(function() {
      $(this).css('background', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
      $(this).css('color', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
     })


  }
     });
```

but now I need to change the `$('#slider-1-nav-ul a').each(function() {` part to not to look at all tabs, but on the one that has just been clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: Create jsfiddle/show complete relevant code

Comment: Ok, the full relevant code is in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class to each (here I use `.tabs`) `div`element, it makes easy to loop over those `div`.
Use use jquery `each` method to loop over all the div

```
$('.liquid-slider .tabs').each(
    function() {
        $(this).click(
            function() {
                alert('you open panel ' + $(this)[0].id);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

**Edit**

Then try this to your project:

```
$('#slider-1-nav-ul a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
            $(this).css('color', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
        });
     })
```

**Explain**

Each loop over all `<a>` element, and `this` represent the current element which is clicked. Then you change the `background` and the `color` of this clicked element.

Hope it helps you!

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/7/)

Comment: Hey, I did what you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/4/ but I don't see the alert unfortunatelly in my case...

Comment: I remove the plugin liquid-slider instantiation and it runs! [http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/6/)

Comment: Hey, yes it works perfectly fine, sorry for late response! I just misunderstood it, because it works when the user presses the title, however the liquidslider script itself changes it so that the title is also shown as a navigation menu bar, see it [here](http://i.imgur.com/7DFMyBR.png) - currently it invokes the alert when I press the header, and not the menu bar, that's why it is so confusing for me

Comment: So set it to resolve! :) And congratz, you did it! :)

Comment: I added an edit to my original Post, could you take a look at it? thanks! :)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your help and for your patience, I really apprieciate it! I have one more question, I promise it will be short - what I want to achieve is to alert the name of the position that user clicks, in one of your previous examples you wrote ` alert('you open panel ' + $(this)[0].id);` and I would like to achieve the effect similar to this now in this settings. Could you help me with that? Thank you very much:)

Comment: I added `alert($(this).id);` below the `$(this).css ...` lines, but I get the popup with `undefined` message. What is more, the popup appears not immediately, but after 2nd click, so user has to click on one position on the menu (nothing happens then), and then again on some other menu position and the popup appears...

Comment: only `alert(this.id);` or `alert($(this)[0].id)` or `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: Hey @Radonirina, thank you so much for your patience and help, finally it works as I wanted! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `alert` out of the `each`, then the message will be displayed only once for each panel.

Answer (score 0):

Add different id to each `<h2>` tag and add the following code in your js

`$(".title").click(function(e){
   var panelName=$(this).attr('id');
   alert(panelName);
});`

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each tab an id to reference with your jquery/javascript

```
<div class="liquid-slider"  id="monitor-slider">
                <div id= "name_this> 
                  <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
                </div>
                <div id= "name_this_different>
                  <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2>
                  <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                </div>          
                <div id= "name_this_different_again> 
                  <h2 class="title">Slide 3</h2>
                  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi.</p>
                </div>

</div>

$("This").click(function(){
    alert("This tab.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to display also the panel name on the alert function? And could you show me exactly where to put this script based on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/) ? Thank you!!

Comment: alert("this panel name"); // because you will have 3 seperate click functions for each tab ...I did it this way so you could alter them to what ever....just add the jquery on the bottom of the body tag in html

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know exactly how the script can refer "This" to the each tab.. Should I change this to some tab indicator? I've got lots of other scripts and divs on my webpage, so the JS might be confused here?
Sorry for my confusion... Am I doing this right here http://jsfiddle.net/6c2ht912/5/ ? This doesn't work properly in my case :(